# How can you emulate a mailing list in Django?

Tags: python, django, mailing-list

I'm on a project which is trying to write what amounts to a Mailing List app in Django, and we're running into a couple of problems/questions.

The code we have so far doesn't set various List headers, and re-sets the To header to be the person we're sending it to, instead of the list address.

Now, we can work our way through all these fiddly little details, but I was wondering if anyone had any code which already did this sort of thing that we could crib from, so that we don't have to go through all the trial-and-error ourselves.  Specific sections of RFCs that showed us what we should be sending would also be useful.

Thanks,
Blake.

Comment: The link to your code so far has 404'd, so please update or remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 2919](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2919.html) has some info and more references on this.

Comment: The page itself wasn't too useful (although we did add the List-Id header field), but the references, specifically http://www.nisto.com/listspec/server-author.html were very useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What about http://labs.freehackers.org/projects/colibri/wiki
It seems to do what you want: a mailing list manager with a django frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at [majordomo](http://www.greatcircle.com/majordomo/), or [mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html)?

Comment: I did, but they don't map particularly well to Django's Email/SMTP classes.  Was there a particular file in one of those packages that you think might help me?  (Since they're both so large, it's hard to know where to get started.)

Comment: I suspect @user29402 was suggesting you dont use Django's email functionality - just run one of those standard mailing list managers, and talk to it via Django. What is the Django front end going to do? Manage subscriptions? mailman has a web front end that does that. Aren't you just duplicating functionality already done elsewhere?

Comment: @Spacedman: Integration, probably. Use the existing User database and access the mailing list directly via Django admin rather than using another app. Also you have more flexibility in setting up a recipients list; in mailman your only option is "Send to everyone on the list". Although I agree that some programs are beter suited to different purposes. So if actual implementation in Django isn't necessary, maybe this would work: https://launchpad.net/django-mailman A django interface to mailman